# Backstage2 ( on LAMP ) Installation troubles

Tags: javascript, php, apache, content-management-system, lamp

I followed all the oultined steps in the instructions (https://github.com/mbassan/backstage2). Moved backstage2 to /var/www/html/backstage2/. Configured the appropiate database settings etc. Installed and enabled the mcrypt module. Added short_open_tag=On to php.ini. But when I go to myurl.com/backstage2/ It shows,

```
print = $_REQUEST['print']; $CFG->url = ($_REQUEST['current_url'] != 'index.php') ? ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z_\-]", "",$_REQUEST['current_url']) : ''; $CFG->action = ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z_\-]", "",$_REQUEST['action']); $CFG->bypass = ($_REQUEST['bypass'] || $CFG->print); $CFG->is_tab = (!$CFG->url) ? 1 : $_REQUEST['is_tab']; $CFG->id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "",$_REQUEST['id']); $CFG->target_elem = ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z_\-]", "",$_REQUEST['target_elem']); $CFG->in_popup = ($CFG->target_elem == 'edit_box' || $CFG->target_elem == 'message_box' || $CFG->target_elem == 'attributes box'); $_SESSION['last_query'] = $_SESSION['this_query']; $_SESSION['this_query'] = 'index.php?'.http_build_query((is_array($_POST)) ? $_POST : $_GET); date_default_timezone_set($CFG->default_timezone); String::magicQuotesOff(); if ($CFG->locale) { setlocale(LC_ALL,$CFG->locale); } if (!$CFG->bypass || ($CFG->bypass && $CFG->print)) { $header = new Header(); $header->metaAuthor(); $header->metaDesc(); $header->metaKeywords(); $header->cssFile('css/colorpicker.css'); $header->cssFile('css/reset.css'); $header->cssFile('css/'.$CFG->skin.'/default.css','all'); $header->cssFile('css/'.$CFG->skin.'/default_ie6.css','all','IE 6'); $header->cssFile('css/'.$CFG->skin.'/default_ie7.css','all','IE 7'); $header->cssFile('css/'.$CFG->skin.'/default_ie8.css','all','IE 8'); $header->jsFile('js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'); $header->jsFile('js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js'); $header->jsFile('js/ajax.js'); $header->jsFile('js/calendar.js'); $header->jsFile('js/colorpicker.js'); $header->jsFile('js/comments.js'); $header->jsFile('js/form.js'); $header->jsFile('js/file_manager.js'); $header->jsFile('js/flow_chart.js'); $header->jsFile('js/gallery.js'); $header->jsFile('js/grid.js'); $header->jsFile('js/multi_list.js'); $header->jsFile('js/popups.js'); $header->jsFile('js/page_maker.js'); $header->jsFile('js/permissions.js'); $header->jsFile('js/swfupload.js'); $header->jsFile('js/jquery.swfupload.js'); $header->jsFile('ckeditor/ckeditor.js'); $header->jsFile('js/Ops.js'); $header->js('CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty[\'span\'] = false;'); $header->display(); $header->getJsGlobals(); } if ($_REQUEST['authy_form']) { $token1 = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "",$_REQUEST['authy_form']['token']); if (!($token1 > 0)) Errors::add('Invalid token.'); if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) { $authy_id = User::$info['authy_id']; $response = shell_exec('curl "https://api.authy.com/protected/json/verify/'.$token1.'/'.User::$info['authy_id'].'?api_key='.$CFG->authy_api_key.'"'); $response1 = json_decode($response,true); if (!$response || !is_array($response1)) Errors::merge('Authy communication error.'); if (!empty($response1['errors']) || $response1['success'] === false || $response1['success'] === 'false') Errors::merge($response1['errors']); if (!is_array(Errors::$errors)) { $_SESSION['token_verified'] = 1; Errors::$errors = false; } } } if (User::isLoggedIn() && !(User::$info['verified_authy'] == 'Y' && !($_SESSION['token_verified'] > 0))) { $CFG->user_id = User::$info['id']; $CFG->group_id = User::$info['f_id']; if (!$CFG->bypass || ($CFG->url == 'edit_page' && !$_REQUEST['tab_bypass'])) { include_once 'includes/popups.php'; ?>
```

What steps can I take to fix this?

EDIT: Installed php5-gd, cant find php5-pcre. All other modules are installed. Error still remains. I am running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Could You paste it as plain text?

Comment: It looks the script is processed like HTML, not PHP.

Comment: Michas, I dont understand. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do You have a plain PHP script working?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing `short_open_tag`? Also did you **added** it or just **changed** `off` to `on`?

Answer (score -1):

Open php.ini and change
short_open_tag = Off
to
short_open_tag = On

restart apache2 and go :)

Comment: He wrote that he set `short_open_tag` to `On` in `php.ini` in his question.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy, OP didn't have it hi-lighted in the text, fwiw

Comment: @StuartSiegler Well, if someone is answering, he should read the question carefully first, not just highlighted parts.